# CSS property: -webkit-nbsp-mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, safari, webkit

Is there an equivalent CSS property of `-webkit-nbsp-mode` for Firefox and IE?

http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-nbsp-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and it will be removed in Blink (the rendering engine used by Chrome and Opera) some time in the future: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227311